# How can i make a post to show up only in the user news feed and not in his time line using ios facebook SDK

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

What i am trying to do is an ios app for sharing achieved goals.

When someone wants to share a goal, it only press the share button and automatically share it in its news feed without showing up a facebook dialog, is this possible? if is not possible, then which types of post should i be looking for?

What i have done so far is the common [share](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/share) for ios, but this shows up the facebook dialog.

PD: I already achieved the facebook login.

Answer (score 1):

The message parameter must be 100% user generated, so you cannot just use `/me/feed` to post a predefined message. You would need to authorize the user with `publish_actions` anyway, and that permission needs to go through a review process. Facebook will definitely not approve it if you prefill the message. See the platform policy for more information about prefilling: https://developers.facebook.com/policy/

> 2.3: Ensure that all content in the user message parameter is entered by the user. Don’t pre-fill. This includes posts, messages, comments,
>   and captions.

You could use Open Graph Actions/Objects or the Achievements API, check out the Facebook docs for information about those possibilities:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/achievements

Answer (score 0):

If you have already achieved the login then using a post on me/feed will be sufficient to post the status. It will be visible to all the people to whom he has given access to his feed from your app.

Comment: But, does the facebook dialog will be shown? I mean the will be writting something else